# Ldap access forbidden spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, ldap, postman

My SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception
   {
      // @formatter:off
      httpSecurity
               .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/boards/**").permitAll()
               .anyRequest().authenticated()
               .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
               .and().exceptionHandling()
               .accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied");
      // @formatter:on
   }
   @Override
   public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
   {
      auth.ldapAuthentication()
          .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
          .userSearchBase("ou=people")
          .userSearchFilter("uid={0}")
          .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
          .groupSearchFilter("uniqueMember={0}")
          .contextSource()
          .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=concretepage,dc=com")
          .and()
          .passwordCompare()
          .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
          .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
   }

   @Bean
   public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
      return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
   }
```

My `ldap.ldif`

```
dn: dc=concretepage,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: domain
objectclass: extensibleObject
dc: concretepage

dn: ou=groups,dc=concretepage,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: groups

dn: ou=people,dc=concretepage,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: people

dn: uid=krishna,ou=people,dc=concretepage,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Krishna Sharma
sn: Sharma
uid: krishna
userPassword: $2a$10$S8V5m0T40n9hhzLtRZpUYuSF38b88axEKIDyVrXtA8b8LN0CB6CRq


dn: uid=surya,ou=people,dc=concretepage,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Surya Singh
sn: Singh
uid: surya
userPassword: $2a$10$FXjepdY6oNJuUGGFEuyPFOJ/i7BjFcW1hfq8WClVjXbVq7suNu2A2

dn: cn=developers,ou=groups,dc=concretepage,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
cn: developers
ou: developer
uniqueMember: uid=krishna,ou=people,dc=concretepage,dc=com
uniqueMember: uid=surya,ou=people,dc=concretepage,dc=com

dn: cn=managers,ou=groups,dc=concretepage,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
cn: managers
ou: manager
uniqueMember: uid=krishna,ou=people,dc=concretepage,dc=com
```

I try to access the `/labels/xxxx` with postdam by passing username and password but i get an accessDenied:
[image]

Second variant with `BasicAuth`
[image]

The `/board/xyqas` is available

Comment: You don't have form nor basic authentication enabled.

Answer (score 0):

i miss the `.and().httpBasic()`

```
httpSecurity
               .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/boards/**").permitAll()
               .anyRequest().authenticated()
               .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
               .and().exceptionHandling()
               .accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied")
               .and().httpBasic();
```